# What does ヤラレ女/やられ女 mean?

Tags: words, definitions

I came across this term on the Internet. It is proving to be very tricky.

- 女 is not too hard. It can be translated as “woman”, “girl”, “female”, and possibly some other terms.
- ヤラレ/やられ is the part I can't seem to grasp. It might be derived from [やる](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%84%E3%82%8B), and I think it might have something to do with sex.

Does anyone know what it means?

Edit: You guys are right. I need to provide some context surrounding the word. So (takes a deep breath), here goes:

There is a website titled 「Midnight Ladies」. In this website, an artist has posted images that show female anime villains (both original characters and characters from existing shows) getting beaten up, killed, or humiliated in a number of ways. For one such image, the artist has some of these characters display...um...”incontinence”. The artist's words on the subject are as follows:

> それから「失禁」。もう今までに何度か描いてますが、水溜りまでシッカリと描き込んだのはこれが初めてですね。私にとって失禁は「負け」の象徴なのです。しかも格の低いやられ役にこそ相応しい痴態で、動物的レベルでの戦意が挫け、自分の存在を放棄した事を表します。性行為以外でこんなに無様で下品な姿を女性が曝す。これはほとんど「ヤラレ女」だけの醍醐味です。

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think it could be translated like this:

> And so the “incontinence”. Now I already drew it several times, but this is the first time I have properly drawn it as only a puddle, right? As far as I am concerned, I can say with confidence that incontinence is a symbol of “defeat”. Moreover, it is precisely the suitable silliness in the low ranking of expendable characters, and their fighting spirit is broken on a sensual level, and represents the fact that they surrendered their existence. Women expose their unsightly and vulgar figures in this way with the exception of sexual intercourse. This is almost the real pleasure of “ヤラレ女” alone.

Oh, and when I tried to look up the meaning of the term, I came across a book title that says やられ女の言い分 (文春文庫) by 内田 春菊. I think that can be translated as “A やられ女's Case” (Bunshun Bunko) by Shungicu Uchida/Uchida Shungicu.

I hope this context helps to provide a better answer, as crass as it may be.

Comment: "Came across this term on the internet" basically implies "every imaginable context". Could you please give the precise context?

Comment: While it's not impossible to guess, this is not an established word, and I cannot tell the correct meaning (nor vote answers) with confidence unless OP shares the context.

Comment: What is the reading for 女 in this term?  My gut says 「め」.

Comment: Context please?

Comment: @Otsukisama: But...I edited my question to include the context, didn't I? (Confused)

Comment: Oops, I guess I misread it sorry ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

遣られる{ヤられる} means to suffer or be damaged. So, I think the phrase in question means damaged/suffering woman.

Maybe if you provide the context we can decipher the meaning.

Answer (score 2):

ヤられ(た) would probably pertain to sex, especially since it's used with 女. やられ役 is used to refer to someone in an expendable role, so I would extrapolate from there. Sorry for being a bit crass, but it likely refers to a woman who is 'used' (and discarded) in some way, or is a 'sl-t'. Google Images brings up some rather crass images of slumped over women.

Comment: やられた is the past passive form of やる, which can mean to beat someone, kill someone, or have sex with someone, typically used to refer to someone below you, to connect back to your comment about how it may be derived from やる

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I just found out that 「Midnight Ladies」 has a Glossary section that explains terms exclusive to the site.

In that section, it has the following term listed:

> やられ
>
> このサイトの核心を成す概念（笑）。物語に敵として登場する女性が戦ってやっつけられる事、つまり「やられちゃう」事。生命の有無は問いませんが（表記が「殺られ」ではなく平仮名なのはそのため）原則は戦闘。処刑や自決はあくまでも例外です。こういうやられ役の女性キャラをここではもっぱら「やられ女」と称しています。でも実はこう言ってしまうと同じ「やられ」でも「犯られ」という雰囲気が強くなり、実際、検索エンジンにかけてみるとそういう結果になってしまうんですよね（笑）。もっと適切で魅力的な呼称を考えています。

The translation into English apparently goes something like this:

> Yarare
>
> The concept that forms the core of this site. (LOL) The act of women, who make appearances as enemies in a story, fighting and being defeated, in other words, the act of “being completely defeated”. Whether they live or not does not matter (That’s why the writing is not “殺られ”, and is in hiragana), but the principle is the fight. Executions and suicides are the only exceptions. Female characters in expendable roles of this kind here are exclusively called “やられ女”. But actually, when I had said this, the atmosphere, which is called “犯られ” is also in the same “やられ”, became stronger. Indeed, when I try to use the search engine, the fact is it would consist of results like that, wouldn’t it? (LOL) I am thinking of a more appropriate and attractive name.

I have to say that I feel embarrassed, because the answer was right in front of me!

On an interesting side note, there is a blog discussing [やられ役](http://eigo-kobako.blog.so-net.ne.jp/2007-06-27).

Apparently, the term やられ役 can be translated as follows:

- expendable character
- ensign expendable
- no-name extra
- redshirt
- disposable
- jobber
- cannon fodder
- loose cannon

That's a lot of translations for one term, isn't it?

By the way, if I screwed up with my translating, please don't hesitate to point out any mistakes!

Comment: So Haran Rajkumar's answer turned to be the correct one :) This やられ is not 犯られ ("raped") but "beaten up, killed, or humiliated in a number of ways", what exactly the site is about.